# Excel VBA - Ignore password prompts

Tags: vba, excel, passwords

I have some code that cycles through several workbooks and makes changes to some headers. The workbooks are unprotected, but they are linked to a workbook that requires a password. I know the password, but it is not needed to complete the task I need done.

Basically, part of my code opens the unprotected workbook I need to make changes to:

```
workbooks.Open filename:="C:\Myfile.xlsm"
```

When this runs, I get a pop-up message that says `Differentfile.xlsx` is protected and asks for a password.

If I close out of this message the rest of the code runs fine.

Is there any way to have VBA automatically close this message or ignore any password requests? I don't want to open it read-only since the code makes and saves changes.

Answer (score 3):

You can include your password:

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:= "C:\Myfile.xlsm", Password:="YourPasswordHere"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

`Application.DisplayAlerts = False`

before the point at which you get the prompt, and this after

`Application.DisplayAlerts = True`